# POST request for adding YouTube video to playlist in Swift

Tags: swift, youtube-data-api

I was looking for some beginner help with implementing the feature to add a YouTube video to the personal watch later playlist.

I am using the request structure shown in the last example here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests. i.e `part=snippet` and the request body is:

```
{
 "snippet": {
  "playlistId": "WL",
  "resourceId": {
   "videoId": "a7SouU3ECpU",
   "kind": "youtube#video"
  },
  "position": 0
 }
}
```

I was wondering how to code this into Swift knowing the videoId you wish to add to the playlist?

I've got OAuth working using the GTLR and GTMOAuth2 frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a video item to your Watch Later playlist using the GTLR framework is actually quite simple.

My solution here makes use of a custom Video class with a property `videoId`

```
let playlistItem = GTLRYouTube_PlaylistItem()
playlistItem.snippet = GTLRYouTube_PlaylistItemSnippet()
playlistItem.snippet!.playlistId="WL"
let resourceId = GTLRYouTube_ResourceId()
resourceId.kind="youtube#video"
resourceId.videoId=video.videoId
playlistItem.snippet!.resourceId = resourceId
let query3 = GTLRYouTubeQuery_PlaylistItemsInsert.query(withObject: playlistItem, part: "snippet")
service.executeQuery(query3, delegate: self, didFinish: nil)
```

To add a selector once the query has been executed, simply replace the nil in the last line of code.

There is an issue if you are dealing with multiple video queries consecutively, so simply add a time delay after each query has been executed.